# How to check user for authentication?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

It is necessary to implement a check for user authentication, and depending on this it displays different screens.
I tried to implement it, but I get an error on the line "FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()". Am I checking correctly? And if so, how can you fix the error? I will be grateful for help
My code:

```js
class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignInScreenState createState() => _SignInScreenState();
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {
  TextEditingController _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _emailTextController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<User>(
        future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            User? user = snapshot.data;
            return HomeScreen();
          } else {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                      hexStringToColor("#a40606"),
                      hexStringToColor("#d98324"),
                    ], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                        20, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2, 20, 0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        logoWidget("images/news_icon.png"),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        reusableTextField("Enter UserName", Icons.person_outline, false,
                            _emailTextController),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        reusableTextField("Enter Password", Icons.lock_outline, true,
                            _passwordTextController),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        forgetPassword(context),
                        firebaseUIButton(context, "Sign In", () {
                          FirebaseAuth.instance
                              .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: _emailTextController.text,
                              password: _passwordTextController.text)
                              .then((value) {
                            Navigator.push(context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
                          }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
                            print("Error ${error.toString()}");
                          });
                        }),
                        signUpOption()
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to set the future property of your FutureBuilder to `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` which returns a value of the type `User?`, however it must be of the type `Future<T>`.

Instead of FutureBuilder, you could use `StreamBuilder` and use `FirebaseAuth.Instance.authStateChanges()` as your stream.

This fires events when the user logs in, logs out and when the stream is registered.

You can read more about it on the FlutterFire docs here:

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/start